# Changed / Uploaded files changed to 0 Bytes / Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload, byte, zero

on my Wordpress Site I can't change or upload files. If I edit a file in Wordpress or upload a new one with filezilla it immediately changes to zero bytes. It happens in every folder and with every file-type

Hope you can help me

Comment: Could it be that you run out of disk space on the server? Are there any error messages (in FileZilla log) ?

Comment: No there wasn't any error message. But you are right. It was the disk space.. I deleted a few big files and now every thing works fine. THANK YOU!